# LWC optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I think optional chaining is a really cool feature and I would like to use it in LWC, plus it's already enabled in Apex, yohoo.

If I try to write something like `state={candidate?.First_Name__c?.state}` Salesforce returns `This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining'`.

In github I found people talking about it in LWC repo, but haven't found actually how to enable it.

Anyone was able to achieve it?

Comment: Could you add a link to where this has been talked about please?

Comment: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1508

Comment: In this article its mentioned that this is. ot supported yet. Also they have told some workarounds which work only for lwc oss.

Comment: ye, that's probably possible for only OSS, for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optional chaining in LWC as of today, as long as the browser in which you're running the app supports it (often the case for modern browsers), as we don't transpile the syntax down. Take a look at a longer explanation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/02/leveraging-the-newest-esxx-features-in-lwc.html).

Comment: yey, thanks a lot for the update. I would have missed it

Comment: How do we get it to work with lwc-jest?

Comment: which problem do you have? for me it's working. Make sure you're using the latests version "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.9.2"

Comment: I found an issue using optional chaining in LWC. It sometimes transforms the code into something funky when it gets minified: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346534/minified-code-in-lwc-is-wrong-because-of-optional-chaining-operator.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

As of now, optional chaining is supported as long as your browser supports it.

---

Optional Chaining also known as the Safe Navigation Operator is a feature of [ECMA 2020 (11<sup>th</sup> edition)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-punctuators),

But LWC supports only the below versions of ECMA Script as of now(Winter 2021)

- ES6 (ECMAScript 2015)
- ES7 (ECMAScript 2016)
- ES8 (ECMAScript 2017)—excluding Shared Memory and Atomics
- ES9 (ECMAScript 2018)—including only Object Spread Properties (not Object Rest Properties)
  Static public fields—currently at TC39 Stage 3

[Supported Javascript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_javascript)

Hopefully, we will get this feature soon!