# Minified code in LWC is wrong because of optional chaining operator

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, bestpractice, operators, safe-navigation-operator

I have a LWC that has a simple getter function that controls whether to display an element or not:

```
get _isGridNotEmpty(){
    return this._gridData?.length > 0;
}
```

However I found that the element never shows because the resulting minified version in the page is this:

[image: Minified version by Salesforce (formatted)]

When I enable lightning debug for my user it works correctly because the code isn't minified.

I also confirmed that it is the optional chaining operator ("?.") which causes this issue. The following code gets minified correctly:

```
get _isGridNotEmpty(){
    return (this._gridData && this._gridData.length > 0);
}
```

Has anyone else encountered issues like this? Should javascript chaining operators be avoided in LWC? Admittedly, my example may not be the best use case for using optional chaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incorrectly minified optional chaining is a known bug.

Here is a quote from the response given by Salesforce support on this issue

> Most probably this should be fixed in the summer 21 release. You can
> always refer to this bug id “W-9154750” for reference and contact
> salesforce if the same issue occurs in the sandbox when the summer 21
> (232) release comes up. Till then we can go with the workaround for
> the issue.

By workaround they mean refactoring the code to remove optional chaining as in your last code example.

Comment: Thank you for this. Good to know that it is indeed a known issue.